# Error while installing lightdm-webkit-greeter

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, webkit

I can't install the package `lightdm-webkit-greeter` on Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm-webkit-greeter
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package lightdm-webkit-greeter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik You need to add `universe` repository to be able to install this package
Please edit Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add `universe` to Your repo.

After that, please `update` Your package list by typing:
`sudo apt-get update`

and then follow with the installation of Your package:
`sudo apt-get install lightdm-webkit-greeter`

For more informations regarding this package You can check this link:
https://launchpad.net/lightdm-webkit-greeter

Answer (score 1):

Update the package lists first

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lightdm-webkit-greeter
```